# Is there any way to make the edited image downloadable in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, web, download

> Hi I am making a web app that takes a normal image and helps you to edit it.

```
> > This is the function for applying the filters on the user image.
function applyFilter() {
  var computedFilters = "";
  controls.forEach(function (item) {
    computedFilters +=
      item.getAttribute("data-filter") +
      "(" +
      item.value +
      item.getAttribute("data-scale") +
      ") ";
  });
  image.style.filter = computedFilters;
  downloadableImage.style.filter = computedFilters;
}

> > > Here I am adding the eventListener for showing the live editing image to the user.
userFile.addEventListener("change", function () {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    localStorage.setItem("userImage", reader.result);
    image.setAttribute("src", localStorage.getItem("userImage"));
    downloadableImage.setAttribute("src", reader.result);
    downloadLink.setAttribute("href", localStorage.getItem("userImage"));
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

> I want to make the image that is downloadable to be edited according to the user.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote and mark as answered.. It helps other people a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to download the image, you just need to add a `download` attribute to the download link.
In your case, do `downloadLink.setAttribute("download", "download")`
**EDIT:**
**Well, I'm not exactly sure about how to do that in your case, but [this link](https://blog.logrocket.com/programmatic-file-downloads-in-the-browser-9a5186298d5c/) may help.
It explains blobs and object URLS, and what you would is:**

1. create a blob and object URL for the image
2. give the download attribute to the `downloadLink`
3. specify the `href` attribute as the blob URL
4. and it works!

**IMPORTANT**
You should also read [this mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) for more information about ObjectURLS.
Remember that you have to delete (revoke) each URL once an edit has been made and create a new ObjectURL:

> Blobs are objects that are used to represent raw **immutable** data. Blob objects store information about the type and size of data they contain, making them very useful for storing and working file contents on the browser.

They are not changed(the raw, immutable data) and therefore should be deleted when you no longer need them:

> Browsers will release object URLs automatically when the document is unloaded; however, for optimal performance and memory usage, if there are safe times when you can explicitly unload them, you should do so

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes) for more info

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already tried that and I want to make the image downloadable but with the edits that user has done.

Comment: thanks for your effort for solving my problem but I can't find the solution for my problem.

Comment: now does it help? Don't give up :).. Sometimes coding is frustrating, and SO exists for solving problems that programmers have after trying hard to find an answer..